# Outlook.com email not centering

Tags: html-email, outlook.com

I am testing out an email template, in Outlook.com it does not align to the middle however on all others clients it does.

I have applied the following class below, but it didn't really help much, just cut off the header

```
.ExternalClass{display:inline-block; line-height: 131%};
```

Here is the whole template: http://jsfiddle.net/29mTG/

Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `align="center"` to any table cell where you want the contents centered.

If you want something vertically centered, add `valign="middle"` to any table cell (the `height=""` must be set).

Answer (score 2):

I can't find where exactly in your template would be causing the problem, but I've found the best thing to do is have a wrapper table with a width of 100% and a `<td align="center">` and nest all of your content tables inside that.

ex:

```
<!-- Wrapper -->
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tr valign="top">
    <td align="center">
        <!-- Body Content -->
        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">
            <tr valign="top">
                <td align="left">
                    content
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also I saw that you were HTML encoding your font-family css, which won't be interpreted correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have Updated the jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/beqLS/

How do I make it fluid/ responsive?

Comment: ...well, on line 8, you have a td containing another td. So get rid of that, then read this- [Campaign Monitor Responsive Email Design Guide](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/guides/mobile/)

Answer (score 1):

All td's must have an align on them, so use `align="center"` as in `<td align="center">CONTENT</td>`

Answer (score 1):

I centered the entire email by simply wrapping everything inside
`<div style="text-align: center;">EMAIL SOURCE CODE GOES HERE</div>`